# Change the outermost svg size but preserve the size of everything inside that svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

Is it possible to change the outermost `svg` size but preserve the size of everything inside that `svg`?

I was not able to find the solution for that on the Internet.

In order to avoid `x-y problem` I will describe my use case for this.

> I have a `div`. The `div` has `overflow-y: scrollable`. So, that means that when my  outermost `svg` (which is a direct child of the `div`) will become larger than the `div` I will be able to scroll to see the whole `svg`.
>
> At first the width and height attributes of the `svg` are set to `100%`.
>
> When it is necessary I scale the `svg` vertically (i.e. I am increasing the viewport) and when the `svg` does not fit into the `div` I am getting a nice scroll bar.
>
> The prodblem is that everything inside the `svg` is relative to the `svg` and when the `svg` gets scaled the content gets scaled as well and I would like to avoid the content scaling.

I thought about using the `viewBox` and change it when the `svg` scales, but I did not have a `viewBox` initially, so I can not do that.

An attempt to use a `viewBox` to solve the problem was unsuccessfull because the `viewBox` attribute affects other `svg`s.
Here is my `svg` without `viewBox` attribute being applied:

[image]

Here is my `svg` with `viewBox` attribute being applied:

[image]

Here is the upper `svg`, it is not connected to the lower `svg` in any way, but still it gets affected after the changing of the `viewBox` attribute in the lower `svg`:

[image]

Comment: I don't see why you can't add a viewBox

Comment: @RobertLongson, because for some reasons it affects another `svg`. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: I think we're going to need an [mcve] here. Can you add one to the question please?

Comment: When you say "affected" do you mean that the lower one gets moved down the page a bit?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau, yes I mean exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The prodblem is that everything inside the svg is relative to the svg and when the svg gets scaled the content gets scaled as well and I would like to avoid the content scaling.

To stop that you will need to make sure that the `viewBox` aspect ratio stays the same as the SVG viewport aspect ratio.

As an example, if you scale your SVG to `width="200"`, `height="600"` (ie an aspect ration of 1:3), then you need to make sure your viewBox has the same aspect ratio.  Eg. `viewBox="0 0 200 600"` or `viewBox="0 0 100 300"` etc.

If that doesn't work, then you need to supply a working example of the page so we can see what you are actiually doing.

Comment: But what if the `svg` for which I provide the `viewBox` has `width` and `height` set to `100%`?

Comment: In that case "scaling the SVG" is equivalent to "scaling its parent div".  See: http://jsfiddle.net/xgqs0avc/3/

Comment: I understand it. The aspect ration of the parent is dynamic (if we will take the responsiveness into consideration), so I can not tweak the `viewBox` and preserve the aspect ration at the same time. In other words the initial (default, provided by the system `viewBox` is dynamic as well).

Comment: Yes, in the fiddle you provided you have a fixed size of the `div`, but what if I will try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xgqs0avc/4/)? As you can see it moves down. It seems there is no solution for the problem. ) :

Comment: In that instance, that is because we are using `display: inline-block`. Inline blocks get their bottoms lined up on the text baseline.  If you use `display:block` instead, you don't have that issue: http://jsfiddle.net/xgqs0avc/14/  But I don't think this is the same as your original problem.

Comment: I am reading [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/expanded-toc.html) documentation on svg and never heard about something like that. Where did you read about it?

Comment: The way images (including embedded SVG images) are displayed in web pages, is governed by the HTML spec, not the SVG one.